# Priority based multithreading?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-priority

I have written code for two threads where is one is assigned priority 20 (lower) and another on 10 (higher). Upon executing my code, 70% of the time I get expected results i.e high_prio (With priority 10) thread executes first and then low_prio (With priority 20).

Why is my code not able to get 100 % correct result in all the executions? Is there any conceptual mistake that I am doing?

```
void *low_prio(){
    Something here;
}

void *high_prio(){
    Something here;
}

int main(){

    Thread with priority 10 calls high_prio;
    Thread with priority 20 calls low_prio;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the priority of the main thread?

Comment: you mean main () ?

I have just two threads. they are not childs of any other threads.

Comment: When the work to be done is super small, and you launch the low priority thread first, it's wholly possible for it to complete its work before the second thread launches at all.

Comment: @immibis: While I'm not super sure of this, the main thread's default scheduling being non-`FIFO` may mean it's supposed to be immediately preempted by even a low priority `FIFO` thread (though clearly that's not happening since the OP's results are inconsistent).

Comment: your 1st comment makes more sense. I ll run a loop and test it.

Comment: I tried putting printf inside a loop that is running 1000 times. I am getting mixed and inconsistent results. I expect my code to finish high_prio first before switching to low_prio.

Comment: even if I create high_prio in my main first and then low_prio, output is still inconsistent with high_prio not always executing on priority.

Comment: the posted ?code? tells us nothing.  Please post a [mcve] so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any conceptual mistake that I am doing?

Yes — you have an incorrect expectation regarding what thread priorities do.  Thread priorities are not meant to force one thread to execute before another thread.

In fact, in a scenario where there is no CPU contention (i.e. where there are always at least as many CPU cores available as there are threads that currently want to execute), thread priorities will have no effect at all -- because there would be no benefit to forcing a low-priority thread not to run when there is a CPU core available for it to run on.  In this no-contention scenario, all of the threads will get to run simultaneously and continuously for as long as they want to.

The *only* time thread priorities may make a difference is when there is CPU contention -- i.e. there are more threads that want to run than there are CPU cores available to run them.  At that point, the OS's thread-scheduler has to make a decision about which thread will get to run and which thread will have to wait for a while.  In this instance, thread priorities can be used to indicate to the scheduler which thread it should  prefer allow to run.

Note that it's even more complicated than that, however -- for example, in your posted program, both of your threads are calling `printf()` rather a lot, and `printf()` invokes I/O, which means that the thread may be temporarily put to sleep while the I/O (e.g. to your Terminal window, or to a file if you have redirected stdout to file) completes.  And while that thread is sleeping, the thread-scheduler can take advantage of the now-available CPU core to let another thread run, even if that other thread is of lower priority.  Later, when the I/O operation completes, your high-priority thread will be re-awoken and re-assigned to a CPU core (possibly "bumping" a low-priority thread off of that core in order to get it).

Note that inconsistent results are normal for multithreaded programs -- threads are inherently non-deterministic, since their execution patterns are determined by the thread-scheduler's decisions, which in turn are determined by lots of factors (e.g. what other programs are running on the computer at the time, the system clock's granularity, etc).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense now. However, is there a way native to Linux to restrict this to one core of my CPU ?

Comment: I took your suggestion and implemented the same on a single core. I am not able to run 1 thread at a time not necessarily in the priority that I want. Sometimes thread with lower priority runs first and sometimes one with higher runs first. At a given time only 1 thread is running though.